# How to copy at most n collection elements in Smalltalk?

Tags: collections, smalltalk

Is there an elegant one-liner to copy at most n elements in a collection?

I find writing the following cumbersome:

```
limit := collection size min: n.
copy := collection copyTo: limit
```

Is there a better way?

Edit - and also a bit harder problem: copy at most the *last* n elements

Comment: I would use `#first:` instead of `#copyTo:`, because it has a companion `#last:`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are also the stream messages:

```
'foobar' readStream next: 3.
'foobar' readStream next: 10.
```

In Squeak/Pharo use `next:`, it will automatically truncate when there is not as many element available as requested.

In other dialects like VW & Dolphin use the more explicit `nextAvailable:` to avoid an error.

Comment: Nice! aka.nice! In other dialects where `#next:` may not truncate, try `#peek:` which likely will.

Comment: Nice! sadly it does not work for last. I find it curious that Smalltalk lacks a lot in the area of manipulating strings and other collections (compared to python for example)

Comment: @melkyades Good question. I would say that most Smalltalkers prefer not to populate basic classes such as `String`, etc., with too many methods. If a particular project would benefit from some extensions, it will add them for its own convenience. This is what Andrei Chis suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41833228/4081336).

Answer (score 6):

There's no dedicated message, but why not:

```
aCollection first: (aCollection size min: n)
```

and

```
aCollection last: (aCollection size min: n)
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if there is already a method that does exactly his, but you can add one:

```
SequenceableCollection>>#copyAtMost: n
   ^ self first: (self size min: n)
```

Then you can have:

```
collection := 1 to: 100.
collection copyAtMost: 101
```